# Bind only image without text in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to display images in a dropdown list menu? I can show it in one dropdown list, but I want to display it in multiple dropdownlists.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
    $("DropDownList1").msDropDown();
}
catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
});
```

Comment: can someone help to change the font color of dropdownlist.i tried using select option nth child but after getting selected the color does not appear to the menu which the menu had earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't knows this can help you.but I know your JQuery selector  is wrong.you can use this if your selection is by ID

```
$("#IdName").msDropDown();
```

And if your selection is by class you can use this

```
$(".className").msDropDown();
```

In first case it effects on one object.but in second case it effects on all object that their class name are same

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i made a typo graphical error.But how can I use the similar code in case of multiple dropdownlist.i have some about 70 dropdownlist in that case.Can u help me with this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a same class for all of them and then use the second pattern,you can use $(".className")

Comment: @MrinalBari Your welcome.please mark me as answer.thanks